# An invertible matrix that minimizes the norm of the product with a given matrix

Tags: matrix, constrained-optimization

Given a fat matrix $B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ (where $m > n$) with full row rank, I would like to find (numerically) a full-rank matrix $A$ that minimizes the Frobenius norm of the product $A B$. Formally,

$$\underset{A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}{\text{minimize}} \quad \frac{1}{2} \|AB\|_F^2 \quad \text{subject to} \quad \det (A) \neq 0$$

The value of $m$ is typically an order of magnitude larger than $n$. The sizes ($n,m$) I am interested in may be on the order of hundreds.

I have found the following [discussion](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19840/optimization-with-matrix-determinant-as-constraint), which I guess could be generalized to the above case. I wonder if there is a simpler solution in this particular scenario.

Comment: There needs to be a stronger constraint than just $\det A \neq 0$. Otherwise given any ``optimal'' $A$, you can get a better solution still satisfying the constraint by scaling $A$ down, like $\frac{1}{2}A$.

Comment: Right, I missed that. What if we add the constraint $|A|_F=1$?

Comment: Take $B = [I, 0]$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix of size n x n). Then $AB = [A, 0]$ and the Frobenius norm of $AB$ is the Frobenius norm of $A$. So your constraint does not seem appropriate.

Comment: hmm, I do not see a problem with your example. In this case, I am fine with the optimization providing some invertible matrix $A$ whose Frobenius norm is $1$. What do you mean by "not seem appropriate"?

Comment: The question to answer here is whether the set of invertible matrices is bounded and closed (i.e., compact) in the space ${\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ equipped with the Frobenius norm. Using the example in @user7440's comment, if the set of invertible matrices is not compact, then you can find a sequence $A_k$ of invertible matrices whose norm $\|A_k\|_F$ decreases as $k\rightarrow 0$ but which does not converge in the set of invertible matrices.

Comment: Indeed, take the simplest case, $n=1$, and consider the sequence $A_k=\frac{1}{k}$. These matrices are invertible, their Frobenius norm decreases and converges to zero, but the limit point $A=0$ is not a set of invertible matrices.

Comment: If you add your constraint $\|A\|_F=1$, you need to go to $n=2$, where I posit the following sequence: $A_k = [[ \sqrt{1-1/k}, 0], [0, \sqrt{1/k}]]$. All of these are minimizers of the original problem with the special choice $B$, and all are invertible, but the limit point is not invertible.

Comment: Does the need to limit the Determinant cam from the problem itself or just trying to exclude the trivial solution?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth thank you for providing these examples. They highlight the shortcomings of the optimization problem I had in mind. I wonder of such cases are truly common or in fact they are rare. At this point, I am looking for a practical solution. In practice, the matrix $B$ is not of the form user7440 suggested.

Comment: @Royi, indeed -- the invertibility of $A$ is essential. I am fine with relaxations to this constraint, though.

Comment: @Kawhi  $B = [I, 0]$ is useful because the full SVD of $B$ yields $B = U [S, 0] V^T$ where $S$ is diagonal. $AB = AU [S, 0] V^T$ and $$||AB||_{F} =  || AU [S, 0] ||_{F} = || U^T AU [S, 0] ||_{F} = || [CS, 0] ||_{F}$$ where $C = U^T A U$ lies in the same set as $A$ (because the Frobenius norm is invariant by multiplication with an orthogonal matrix)

Comment: @Kawhi: As the example in the previous comment shows, "the matrix $B$ is not of the form user7440 suggests" and "whether such cases are truly common" is looking at this the wrong way. In general, unless you can *prove* that something cannot happen, it *will* happen for one set of data or another, and you need to have a formulation that takes that into account.

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem you are running into is that "matrix is invertible" is a statement that is numerically not stable. The matrix $[[1,0],[0,0]]$ is not invertible, but if you perturb it *infinitesimally*, it is. Similarly, a small perturbation of $[[1,0],[0,1e-38]]$ makes this invertible matrix non-invertible. That is because the dependence of the eigenvalues on the entries of the matrix is continuous, and whether or not an eigenvalue happens to cross the zero (therefore yielding a zero determinant) for a given set of entries is essentially a random event.

Comment: In other words, the statement $\text{det}\ A \neq 0$ is not something you can enforce in actual computations because it excludes too few matrices (essentially none). A statement such as $|\text{det}\ A| > 0.1$, on the other hand, makes sense.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A is square as it should be invertible.